# How do I change the Super-Alt-RightClick combination for the panel edit menu in Gnome Classic?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-panel

I can use Super-Alt-RightClick on the Gnome panel in Gnome Classic (Ubuntu 12.04) and this gives the edit menu (Add to Panel, Properties, etc...).

How can I change this? I would like to either change it to just RightClick, or remove the Super and make is Alt-RightClick.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not hard to change it to just Alt-RightClick.  The need to press the Super button in addition is actually a bug.  Open "CompizConfig Settings Manager" and then select the "Move Window" plugin from the "Window Management" section.  Change the "Initiate Window Move" option to use a modifier key other than "Alt".